How to get user's ip address in Yesod
I'm developing a website with Yesod scaffold. When I try to get the user's ip address (or socket address) by
remoteHost <$> waiRequest

it always returns the local host ip 127.0.0.1 (with different ports).
I have also set "ip-from-header" to "true" in the config file, but nothing changes.
So, how to get the user's ip?
